# Will Windows XP users still be able to install Google Chrome from April 2016?

Tags: windows-xp, installation, google-chrome

As I understand, from April 2016, users of Google Chrome on Windows XP and Windows Vista will still be able to use Google Chrome however it will not receive updates and security fixes (https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/wrMB9YbD5vk).

From April 2016, if someone was running Windows XP and did not already have Google Chrome installed, would they be able to install Google Chrome and how would they go about it?

Furthermore, what would the user journey be like for the following user groups:

- Users in a home environment running Google Chrome. These users have administrative rights over their computer.
- Users in a work environment running Google Chrome for Work. These users may not have administrative rights on their workstation and software installations may be centrally managed.

Answer (score 1):

It is likely that from April 2016, a Windows XP user will be able to download an installer from Google however the installer will check the OS and fail.

Why? [Sarjoor on the Google Chrome Help Forum](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/oY740biJl0M) describes that this was the behaviour when support was dropped for other operating systems in the past.

Users would not be able to download an installer for an older version of Google Chrome from Google.

Why? Google Chrome is evergreen. Google only provides an installer for the most recent version.

Sources:

[sarjoor's answer, Will Windows XP users still be able to install Google Chrome from April 2016?, Google Chrome Help Forums](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/oY740biJl0M).

Answer (score 0):

I believe installation is still possible they will just no longer provide updates to the browser.  However a previous version of chrome will need to be installed.

But like anything that stops receiving updates, it may eventually stop working due to core changes.